# What are the different programming language concepts and which languages show them in a pure way

Tags: programming-languages, paradigms

I am no language expert but I'm recently into languages and trying to get an overview of major concepts and "their" languages. This is similar to [another question about books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376165/books-about-language-paradigms-and-concepts). So first, what are the major programming language concepts, e.g.

- structured
- procedural
- object orientated
- object orientated - prototype based (e.g. Java Script)
- functional (e.g. Haskell)
- logic orientated (e.g. Prolog)
- meta (if a pure concept of it's own?)
- stack based (e.g. Forth)
- math based/array oriented (e.g. APL)
- declarative
- concatenative (e.g. PostScript)
- (definitely incomplete list...)

and second to get a good crasp of these concepts, what would be the programming language that's based on/implementing its core concept most naturally and pure?

- For example Java is OO, but it's not a good example because it's not pure OO due to atoms.
- Lisp is a known to be a functional language, but it's multi-paradigm, so it's not pure. But Lisp may be a pure implementation of "list-based" (if it counts as concept).
- Is there a language that's structured (no GOTO) but not procedural? (Maybe XSLT v1.x)

Comment: Smalltalk is not prototypal. SELF is. Also, a number of the "concepts" above are not orthogonal. One would have to talk about *specific aspects* of each language in comparison with each other (even the terms above may change meaning based on context/language). SQL is also "set oriented" (but a "declarative query language"), not table oriented :-)

Comment: @pst thanks, I removed the wrong examples.

Comment: By the way, thanks for not choosing Java as prime OO example.

Comment: Similar answer @ "Programmer": http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/1719/if-one-is-to-learn-a-new-programming-language-each-year-what-should-the-list-be/7389#7389

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are important languages to learn to understand different approaches and concepts?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3958630/what-are-important-languages-to-learn-to-understand-different-approaches-and-con)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to *JUST MY correct OPINION*'s answer I was pointed in the right direction. I will give the list of paradigms together with their pure languages as far as I found out till now:

- imperative

  - non-structured --- early BASIC, Assembly
  - structured --- ?
  - procedural --- ?
  - modular --- Modula-2, maybe Pascal
  - object-oriented

    - class-based --- Smalltalk
    - prototype-based --- Self, maybe Java Script, Lua
- declarative --- SQL, Regular Expressions, CSS

  - logic --- Mercury, maybe Prolog
  - functional --- Scheme, Haskell

    - tacit/point-free

      - concatenative --- Joy, Cat

On a different "axis" we have

- scalar --- most of them
- array --- APL

Don't know where to put it:

- stack based --- Forth, Postscript

Answer (score 8):

The term you're looking for here is "programming paradigm" and there are [a whole lot of them](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_paradigm) out there.  You can get a list of languages which support each from that Wikipedia page and its follow-up links.

For "pure" renditions of any of these, that's harder because it depends on what level of purity you're looking for.

- For pure structured (under any sufficiently-loose definition of "pure" here) you can look, for instance, at [Modula-2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modula-2).
- For pure object-orientation you're looking primarily at [Smalltalk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smalltalk_%28programming_language%29) and its ilk if you want absolutely everything to be uniformly treated (not actually necessary under the most common definitions!) or you're looking at languages like [Java](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_%28programming_language%29) and [Eiffel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eiffel_%28programming_language%29) if you'll accept primitive types under that heading.
- For functional you're looking most likely at [Haskell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haskell_%28programming_language%29).
- For logic programming the archetypical language is [Prolog](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prolog), but it's not really pure.  The only (mostly-)pure logic language I know of is [Mercury](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercury_%28programming_language%29), and that only if you view its functional chunks as being essentially compatible with its logical chunks.

...and so on and so on.  You get the idea.

Comment: +1 esp. for the Wikipedia link, hadn't seen it before. But the paradigms feel a bit low level to me, as there are usually serveral grouped together. Still a good beginning with procedural, OO, FP, Logic. Thanks.

Comment: I'd actually nominate Ruby over Smalltalk for pure object-orientation. Granted, Smalltalk was first here, but Ruby followed in its footsteps -- everything is an object in Ruby too (including literals and class definitions), and Ruby is more modern, more popular, and arguably easier to use.

Comment: @Ben Lee Agree that Ruby is more pure OO but also has some functional aspects, Closures, map, Continuations, etc. Propably every modern language is multi-paradigm?

Comment: OK, this is going to be entertaining.  Precisely in which way is Smalltalk less pure an OO language than Ruby?  Give specifics, not hand-wavy generalities.

Answer (score 2):

I think Pascal is the canonical procedural language.

I also think Lisp (ironically not ML) is the canonical "meta" language.

For one, a macro is a program fragment which modifies a data structure that represents a program fragment---so you use the language to tweak the language.  Secondly, it's considered common practice to write self-hosting interpretors, traditionally called metacircular evaluators: they are programs which programs and run them.

Of course, any other language can do that.  In Python you have access to the python compiler, and PyPy is a python implementation in python.  But Lisp has, I think, the strongest tradition of doing this.

But I'm a Lisp outsider, so what do I know... 'hope-this-helps ;-)